# Unable to start Docker in WSL2 using new Windows Terminal

Tags: docker, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I have recently installed WSL2  and installed Ubuntu from Microsoft Store.When i run docker using

Sudo service docker start, i get below message

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I followed steps as per this Answer and did below

```
    sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

But still cant start docker..when checking Docker logs, i could see below

> CONNECTING" module=grpc Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
>   Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
>   (exit status 3)
>   `

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have tried a lot of steps based on the error below

> can't initialize iptables table nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?) Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded. (exit status 3) `

But Starting Terminal as administrator worked.Even though you run

```
sudo service docker start
```

The Terminal should be launched as Admin

Comment: OMG I can't believe this was my problem

Comment: So simple... Thanks!

Comment: Launching PowerShell as Administrator solved the problem for me!! So much thanks

Comment: If anyone is getting "CHAIN_ADD failed (No such file or directory): chain PREROUTING" because you are using Debian, refer to this: https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269/2

Comment: Was struggling with this for the past two days, the docker was running, but the hello-world did not! This simple yet effective trick worked wonders! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: This works, indeed, but it's a pain to always start it as administrator. The correct and stable solution seems to set the distro to explicitly use wsl 2, as stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73164601/3207147 to this same question

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

from https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269

Answer (score 7):

I might be late but I faced similar problem and the solution was completely different.
I am posting here for someone if he/she gets similar issue.

## Problem I Faced.

I setup wsl and docker in my new machine.
I can not run dockerd in wsl2. As TheGameiswar suggest I can start the dockerd if I run the terminal as Admin but I still can not run any image.

## The root cause

By default the wsl is version 1 (wsl 1) and docker required wsl2.

## Solution

Set the default wsl version to 2

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

set the installed distro to wsl2

```
wsl --set-version  Ubuntu-20.04 2
```

Comment: Can confirm - I followed a variety of guides online, and even after ensuring I *upgraded* to WSL 2 - bizarrely the need to SET the system to USE WSL2 was another, opaque, step.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great guide [here](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/08/run-linux-containers-with-docker-desktop-and-wsl-2/) which gives some up to date instructions and some prerequisites on using WSL 2 and the new docker desktop.